# How can I load a project from a network drive in visual studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net

I have windows 7 64 bit installed on vmware and visual studio 2015 enterprise. When I am trying to load a project from a network drive vs throws up this error and I cannot load the project.

[image: Network drive error loading project]

I have scoured the internet but cannot find a way to load, build and run a web project (asp.net mvc) project from a network drive.

What can I do?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I also use a VM for development and ran into the same problem. Is there a specific reason as to why your code is stored on a network drive? If not then I suggest storing it on the VM's local disk.

Comment: I use several VM with different VS + SQL Server configuration depending on client requirement. I would like to have all my projects in one place (network/host) drive and be able to use different VM (not for the same project though). 

Reason you asked...
I'll be damned if I do not copy the local VM disk project back to my network drive before poweroff and my VM crashes for some reason.

Comment: Agreed... your repository should be disposable on the VM. For this I use GIT. So in your case, you can set up a local repository on the VM with a git remote pointing to the files on the network.